# How do I convert a string version of a number in an arbitrary base to an integer?

Tags: string

how to convert string to integer??

for ex:

- "5328764",to int base 10
- "AB3F3A", to int base 16

any code will be helpfull

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: -1 for not using obvious ref documents.

Comment: Do you mean programming language, or written language? His question isn't in English, either.

Comment: why the downvotes, he says any code will help him!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming arbitrary base (not 16, 10, 8, 2):

In C (C++), use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/)

```
return strtol("AB3F3A", NULL, 16);
```

In Javascript, use `parseInt`.

```
return parseInt("AB3F3A", 16);
```

In Python, use `int(string, base)`.

```
return int("AB3F3A", 16)
```

In Java, use [`Integer.parseInt`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) (thanks Michael.)

```
return Integer.parseInt("AB3F3A", 16);
```

In PHP, use [`base_convert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php).

```
return intval(base_convert('AB3F3A', 16, 10));
```

In Ruby, use `to_i`

```
"AB3F3A".to_i(16)
```

In C#, write one yourself.

Comment: Why the downvote?  If this is a legitimate novice question then KennyTM really covered the bases.  If this is a homework question then  using a standard library function is probably not allowed so we're not doing the work for the OP.

Comment: I suspect the downvote would be for the reply from Michael Mrozek - Int32.Parse is bad because it cannot handle empty strings, throwing an exception. Better to use Convert.ToInt32 or Convert.ToInt64, etc.

Comment: In hope it could be helpful to somebody, here are few more conversion methods for C/C++ -  http://www.lazarenko.me/downloads/code/ascii_to_bin/ascii_to_binary.c

Answer (score 0):

9999 is really 9000 + 900 + 90 + 9
So, start at the right hand side of the string, and pick off the numbers one at a time.
Each character number has an ASCII code, which can be translated to the number, and multiplied by the appropriate amount.

Answer (score 0):

in C#, i think it is: Convert.ToInt64(value, base)
and the base must be 2, 8, 10, or 16

Answer (score 0):

Two functions  in java, in both directions: "code" parameter represent the numerical system: "01" for base 2, "0123456789" for base 10, "0123456789abcdef" for hexdecimal and so on...

````
public String convert(long num, String code) {
    final int base = code.length();
    String text = "";
    while (num > 0) {
        text = code.charAt((int) (num%base)) + text;
        num /= base;
    }
    return text;
}

public long toLong(String text, String code) {
    final long base = code.length();
    long num = 0;
    long pow = 1;
    int len = text.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        num += code.indexOf(text.charAt(len - i - 1)) * pow;
        pow *= base;
    }
    return num;
}

println(convert(9223372036854775807L,"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"));
println(convert(9223372036854775807L,"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@=-+*/^%$#&()!?.,:;[]"));
println(toLong("Ns8T$87=uh","0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@=-+*/^%$#&()!?.,:;[]"));```
````

in your example:

```
toLong("5328764", "0123456789") = 5328764
toLong("AB3F3A", "0123456789ABCDEF") = 11222842
```