# Algorithm: Printing the correct index for the character sequence

Tags: algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I came across the following problem while preparing for an exam:

Imagine an alphabet of words. Example:

```
a ==> 1
b ==> 2
c ==> 3
...
z ==> 26
ab ==> 27
ac ==> 28
...
az ==> 51
bc ==> 52
and so on.
```

The sequence of characters needs to be in ascending order only (i.e. 'ab' is valid but 'ba' is not).

**Question**: Given any word, print its index if valid and 0 if not.

```
Input Output
ab 27
ba 0
aez 441
```

Any pointers on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything?  What didn't work?  You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: You forgot about ``aa`` is it on purpose ?

Comment: @CarlNorum: I haven't been able to make any headway.
@SamIam: I have highlighted the question.
@hivert: No `aa` hasn't been left on purpose. The sequence needs to be in strictly increasing order only. So, `aa` should give 0 as the output.

Comment: @hivert: `aa` is not in "ascending order".

Comment: I don't think you want an algorithm. I think you want a formula.

Comment: @Geobits Probably, though if that's the case, the OP probably would benefit to see how the formula was derived.

Comment: I have formatted the question a bit to make it easier to read. :)

Comment: remove illegal number (ie. non-ascending), then treat it as a base 26 numbering system.  Am I missing something?  How does this get upvotes?

Comment: Not quite base 26.  Note we skip aa, ba, bb, etc.

Comment: @Andrew: Once you "remove illegal numbers", it's not a base 26 numbering system anymore. The problem is not that simple. But if you think it is, write up your algorithm in detail as an answer (preferably with code or pseudo-code)

Comment: ahh, good point.  I'm kind of busy, but it seems that is just subtracting (value at previous place) from each place with the first one being considered 0

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495167/given-a-word-print-its-index-words-can-be-increased-accordingly/17514668#17514668

Comment: @user1125600: Yepp! The same question. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me give you a few hints:

- Can you find a formula for the number of such words of a given length `k` ?
- Now fix a length `k`, and a letter `l`. How many word of length `k` starting with `l` are they ?

Hint: Pascal triangle. If you need some more hint, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinadic can help. If you need some implementation, you can get inspiration from the rank function defined in (Python language) https://github.com/sagemath/sagelib/blob/master/sage/combinat/choose_nk.py

Comment: You mean, like, count the ways to **choose** `k` letters out of 26? And so on? :-)

Comment: This seems interesting. Let me scratch my head on this. :D

Comment: For k=1, there would be 26 such words.
For k=2, there would be (25+24+...+1+0) such words.
For k=3, there would be ((24+23+...+1) + (23+22+...+1) + (22+21+...+1) + ... + (2+1) + (1)) such words.
This somewhat seems _Dynamic Programming_ to me. :S

Comment: Yes ! If you want to compute the full association table, this is closely related to computing pascal triangle by some kind of Dynamic Programming algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

1. make sure the input is letters only.  Fail if not.
2. Setup a loop based on the string length minus 1.
3. "Subtract" the value of the first letter in the string from the next.  If the value is zero or positive, you are done as the string is non-ascending so return 0.
4. Repeat by moving up the string one letter at a time checking the next letter.
5. If you get to the end, it is an ascending order string.

To be fair, I have not mentioned an algorithm on how to calculate the index value, just the exit case.  But it gives you a start in the right direction and calculating the index will follow the same framework.

More Info:

Start counting upwards on first letter.  When you hit 'z', reset to next valid string and keep counting -> "aa" fails don't count it.  Add to next which here is "ab".  Once you hit "az", try "ba" - fail, keep adding letters until you get a valid string "bc" and start counting again.  It's like an odometer that counts upwards.

Dang slow, but it should work as it is what you do manually to get the answer.

BTW, there is a much more elegant solution hinted at by @hivert that would be nearly instant to calculate...

Comment: I think you are skipping the hard part of the question.

Comment: I'm trying to leave as much meat on the bone as possible for OP.  I wasn't sure how much "help" he was looking for at first, so I gave just a small framework hint to start.  I can (try to?) add more later if needed.  It could always be done as a brute force if needed pretty simply.  Just count up and when you hit the end of the alphabet, "adjust"  :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: I was able to come up with something similar to discard the invalid sequences. Generating the output for a valid string is what is troubling me. :)

Comment: There is a mathematical solution hinted at by @hivert

Comment: Got it - Ok, I'll add a brute force approach real quick then.  Others can handle a more elegant solution such as the answer from below ;)